# Sharepoint 2010 Task list: Due date = Start date + 1 month

Tags: list, date, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, task

I want to auto-fill the Due date column by taking the Start date column and add 1 month to it.
This formula I've tried in different ways:

=DATE([Start Date]+[Gap],"dd-mm-yyyy") (I created Gap column as number type and filled it with 28 days; in our language, dd-mm-yyyy seems to be the usual way of showing dates in Sharepoint).

Sharepoint keeps on giving back errors.

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:

```
=DATE(YEAR([Start Date]);MONTH([Start Date])+[Gap];DAY([Start Date]))
```

where [Gap] value is integer.

Note: pay attetion to delimiters - they are locale-dependent, most probably you need to replace `,` with `;`